# How to display cart details along with sub totals discount coupon in magento checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

> How to display cart details along with sub totals discount coupon code
>   etc inside shipping methods section in magento checkout page

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cart items like this:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    //do Something with $item
    //here are some examples on how you can get the data for an item
    //use as you wish
    $itemName = $item->getName();
    $itemQty = $item->getQty();
    $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
}
```

You can get the subtotal like this:

```
$subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

and the coupon code

```
$code = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
```

Put all of these in a template and add it to the checkout page through a layout file.

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="right">
       <block type="core/template" name="summary" as="summary" template="path/to/template.phtml"
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```